# Dynamically change combobox size Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, width, dynamically-generated

In Python Tkinter is it possible to dynamically change the size of a `combobox` (the width of the entry widget) based on the length of the selected item?

Comment: Please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()

defaultCar = StringVar()
defaultCar.set("Mercedes Benz")

carList = ["BMW", "Lamborghini", "Honda"]

def resizeFunc():
    newLen = len(cars.get())
    cars.configure(width=newLen+2)

cars = ttk.Combobox(root,
                    textvariable=defaultCar,
                    values=carList,
                    postcommand=resizeFunc)
cars.pack()
```

?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it takes effect only after I select the next box, not immediately. Is there a way to make it spontaneous?

Comment: It takes effect not only after I select the next box, but after I push the drop-down "button", even though I do not select another option. And I do not know any way to make it take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `postcommand` you can use `validate` and `validatecommand`. This will take effect immediately, but there is a caveat. If the combobox has been resized to a width smaller than any of it's choices those choices will be truncated. For instance, using my example, if you select kiwi and then activate the popdown you will see:

- kiwi
- apple
- strawberr
- passion f

**code:**

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)

        items = ["kiwi", "apple", "strawberry", "passion fruit"]

        kws = dict(
            values          = items, 
            validate        = "focus", 
            state           = "readonly",
            validatecommand = self.resize
        )

        self.cb = Combobox(self, **kws)
        self.cb.set(items[0])
        self.cb.pack(anchor="nw")

        self.resize()

    def resize(self):
        self.cb.configure(width=len(self.cb.get())+1)
        return True #must return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.minsize(800, 600)
    app.title("My Application")
    app.mainloop()
```